# Azure fabric SDK webapi not accessible

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I have installed Azure SDk local cluster and set it to cluster 5.

1. Created a simple WebAPI project of stateless ASP.NET core nature.
2. In the servicemanifest file defined the port.
3. In fabric project properties defined the application url with the port.

When i run and deploy the project it shows deployment successful. But when i try to browse to my MVC site it says not found.

What am I missing ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, i am careless. Had selected .NET core 1.0 template